# MUI date picker, add custom values to date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-datepicker

I want to add custom values to the date picker, a percent value to the day.
Can refer to below screenshot

[image]

currently i am using mui date picker and able to display it using below code

```
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';

<DatePicker
maxDate={created_at__lte}
format={DATE_FORMAT}
variant="inline"
name="settlements-from-date-picker"
value={created_at__gte}
autoOk
mask="__-__-____"
onChange={onFilterByFromDate}
renderInput={params => ( <TextField data-sdet="settlements-from-date-picker" {...params} />)}
/>
```

Screenshot of same

[image]

I just want, how I can add those percent values below the day of a specific month